# In Chrome, is there any way to use the search engine shortcut keyword before or after the search string?

Tags: google-chrome, search, keyword

It currently behaves like this:

[typing 'yt test' in the address bar correctly gives this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APeoc.png)

[but 'test yt' just gives this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMpTk.png)

I often want to type the keyword I'm thinking of first rather than the engine/method. The safari extension Keyword Search lets you pick 'front' or 'end'.